# I can't run autotests on my home computer. (Maven)

Tags: java, maven, testing, automation, pom.xml

I'm just getting started in automated testing. I can't run the project at home and I don't understand what's wrong. Please help me.

I have the following pom.xml:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>???</groupId>
    <artifactId>???</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>


    <properties>
        <aspectj.version>1.9.5</aspectj.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.iban4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>iban4j</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.12</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.mail</groupId>
            <artifactId>mail</artifactId>
            <version>1.5.0-b01</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
            <version>42.2.18</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.assertj</groupId>
            <artifactId>assertj-core</artifactId>
            <version>3.17.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
            <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
            <version>3.141.59</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hamcrest</groupId>
            <artifactId>hamcrest-all</artifactId>
            <version>1.3</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
            <version>2.6</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.opencsv</groupId>
            <artifactId>opencsv</artifactId>
            <version>5.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.appium</groupId>
            <artifactId>java-client</artifactId>
            <version>7.0.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
            <artifactId>selenium-ie-driver</artifactId>
            <version>3.141.59</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.qameta.allure</groupId>
            <artifactId>allure-junit4</artifactId>
            <version>2.13.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
            <artifactId>aspectjweaver</artifactId>
            <version>${aspectj.version}</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <sourceDirectory>src</sourceDirectory>
        <testSourceDirectory>src</testSourceDirectory>

        <testResources>
            <testResource>
                <directory>src</directory>
            </testResource>
        </testResources>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>11</source>
                    <target>11</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.22.2</version>
                <configuration>
                    <forkCount>2</forkCount>
                    <reuseForks>true</reuseForks>
                    <testFailureIgnore>false</testFailureIgnore>
                    <rerunFailingTestsCount>2</rerunFailingTestsCount>
                    <argLine>
                        -javaagent:"${settings.localRepository}/org/aspectj/aspectjweaver/${aspectj.version}/aspectjweaver-${aspectj.version}.jar"
                    </argLine>
                    <properties>
                        <property>
                            <name>listener</name>
                            <value>io.qameta.allure.junit4.AllureJunit4</value>
                        </property>
                    </properties>
                    <includes>
                        <include>**/account/**</include>
                        <include>**/objectsMainFlow/**</include>
                        <include>**/dksu/**</include>
                        <include>**/registration/**</include>
                        <include>**/roles/**</include>
                        <include>**/salary/**</include>
                        <include>**/settings/**</include>
                        <include>**/reports/**</include>
                    </includes>
                    <systemProperties>
                        <property>
                            <name>allure.results.directory</name>
                            <value>${project.build.directory}/allure-results</value>
                        </property>
                    </systemProperties>
                </configuration>
                <dependencies>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
                        <artifactId>aspectjweaver</artifactId>
                        <version>${aspectj.version}</version>
                    </dependency>
                </dependencies>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>io.qameta.allure</groupId>
                <artifactId>allure-maven</artifactId>
                <version>2.10.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <reportVersion>2.13.0</reportVersion>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

My goal is to run autotests.

There are test failures.

Please refer to F:\test2??????????\surefire-reports for the individual test results.
Please refer to dump files (if any exist) [date].dump, [date]-jvmRun[N].dump and [date].dumpstream.

[WARNING] Using platform encoding (windows-1251 actually) to copy filtered resources, i.e. build is platform dependent!

SLF4J: Failed to load class "org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder".
SLF4J: Defaulting to no-operation (NOP) logger implementation
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#StaticLoggerBinder for further details.
SLF4J: Failed to load class "org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder".
SLF4J: Defaulting to no-operation (NOP) logger implementation
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#StaticLoggerBinder for further details.

Comment: So it seems there is an issue with SLF4J trying to start up. My guess is that the library is available in the class path where the tests work, but not on your home machine.

Comment: That SLF4J error just means nothing is being logged. This isn't the cause for test failures.

Comment: Maven usually prints which individual tests failed, somewhere above the `There are test failures.` You need to include this information in the question.